# Usage of rootPath property of Site configuration node

Tags: configuration

In the sitecore configuration, we use **site** configuration nodes to define websites.

In that configuration node, there is *rootPath* property with values to sitecore content item.

What is the usage of this *rootPath* setting?

Answer (score 4):

The path to the root item of the site in terms of Sitecore content tree. For example, it is set to /sitecore/content for the “website” site.

[See Documentation](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/rootPath.aspx)